# Define a new geom_xxx for ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I often need a `geom_path` with dark dots inside. 
Hence I would like to have a new `geom_dotpath` that could be used instead of calling 
`geom_path` and `geom_point`.

```
LineColours <- brewer.pal(n=8,name="Paired")

ggplot() +
geom_path(data=mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=qsec), size=1.5, colour=LineColours[3]) +
geom_point(data=mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=qsec), size=1.5, colour=LineColours[4])
```

The best would be, if the new function could use [Generate pairs of bright and dark colours for ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665551/generate-pairs-of-bright-and-dark-colours-for-ggplot2) to find a darker colour automatic.

Comment: You might find it's less work to add new geoms to a plot once you get used to putting all the properties that will apply to the whole graph in the original `ggplot()` call- in your example, `data=mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=qsec)` could be moved into the `ggplot()` call, leaving much less typing for each of the individual geoms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about the color picking, but defining a whole new geom shouldn't really be necessary. You ought to be able to just write a function that returns the relavent layers:

```
geom_dotpath <- function(data,x,y,pathCol,ptCol,...){
  p1 <- geom_path(data = data,aes_string(x = x,y = y),color = pathCol,...)
  p2 <- geom_point(data = data,aes_string(x = x,y = y),color = ptCol,...)
  list(p1,p2)
}

ggplot() + geom_dotpath(data = mtcars,
                        x = "mpg",
                        y = "qsec",
                        pathCol = LineColours[3],
                        ptCol = LineColours[4],
                        size = 1.5)
```